# How to access PGP keys from Kleopatra using C#

Tags: c#, pgp

I have a PGP key pair that I created with Kleopatra and I want to know how I can access it using C#?

I am using the `PgpCore` library to decrypt a file, but it appears I need to feed it the key file and I don't know where it is stored on the machine or the best way to access it.

Is there some way I can query Kleopatra with the ID of the certificate to retrieve the key?

Comment: Can't you just export the key via the GUI and then load it in?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Yes absolutely I could do it that way. Ideally I'd like to be able to programmatically access Kleopatra though if that's possible.

Comment: @BrendanGreen When I try to export the key I can't seem to export it so that it remains encrypted with the pass phrase. Do you know if it is possible to export it from Kleopatra so that it remains encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

Super late to this, but going through this myself. I think you'll have to export the keys, and then point at the file path where you store them to use in C#

**Kleopatra**

***Export private key***: right-click and select 'backup secret keys'

***Export public key***: right-click' export keys' to back up the public key.

**PGPCore code for encryption and decryption**:

[*Encryption*](https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore#encryptstreamasync) using the public key:

```
// Load keys
EncryptionKeys encryptionKeys;
using (Stream publicKeyStream = new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\Keys\public.asc", FileMode.Open))
    encryptionKeys = new EncryptionKeys(publicKeyStream);

PGP pgp = new PGP(encryptionKeys);

// Reference input/output files
using (FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\Content\content.txt", FileMode.Open))
using (Stream outputFileStream = File.Create(@"C:\TEMP\Content\encrypted.pgp"))
    // Encrypt
    await pgp.EncryptStreamAsync(inputFileStream, outputFileStream);
```

[*Decryption*](https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore#decryptstreamasync) using the private key and password:

```
// Load keys
EncryptionKeys encryptionKeys;
using (Stream privateKeyStream = new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\Keys\private.asc", FileMode.Open))
    encryptionKeys = new EncryptionKeys(privateKeyStream, "password");

PGP pgp = new PGP(encryptionKeys);

// Reference input/output files
using (FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\Content\encryptedContent.pgp", FileMode.Open))
using (Stream outputFileStream = File.Create(@"C:\TEMP\Content\decrypted.txt"))
    // Decrypt
    await pgp.DecryptStreamAsync(inputFileStream, outputFileStream);
```

Obviously change the file paths to the corresponding key path, , encrypt = public, decrypt = private